Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') -> at mailchimp.ping.get() function
I'm getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')' for the example given in mailchimp's api docs.
I'm using nextjs with typescript.
This is the code
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');
const api_key = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY;

mailchimp.setConfig({
apiKey: api_key,
server: 'us18',
});

export async function POST(request: NextRequest){

    try {
        const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
        if (response && response.health_status) {
            console.log(response.health_status);
        } else {
            console.error('Unexpected response:', response);
        }
        } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        }
        
    return NextResponse.json('Successfully added to the waitlist!');
}

And here is the error I'm getting
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at isInsideNodeModules (node:internal/util:511:17)
    at showFlaggedDeprecation (node:buffer:178:8)
    at new Buffer (node:buffer:266:3)
    at encoder (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:498:12)
    at RequestBase._auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:431:44)
    at Request.auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:501:15)
    at exports.callApi (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing/src/ApiClient.js:396:13)
    at module.exports.getWithHttpInfo (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing/src/api/PingApi.js:65:27)
    at module.exports.get (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing/src/api/PingApi.js:77:17)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/add-mailing-contact/route.ts:33:47)
    at /Users/mykal/Documents/kurie/kurie-homepage/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:55044

What I'm expecting to get is something in the form of the below however its just throwing an error whenever I try the .get() function.
{
   "health_status": "Everything's Chimpy!"
}


Sounds like a bug in the version of Node that you are using.  Can you switch versions and check?

I had a similar issue with node.js version 20.15 updating to version 20.17 fixed the problem
